# Python:What does OpenCv function cvHaarDetectObjects return?

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I am trying to make a game that uses collision with face.
But i havent figured what cvHaarDetectObjects returns. Here is a smalll snipet of code.

```
cascade = cv.Load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(grayscale, cascade, storage, 1.2, 2,
cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING)

if faces:
    for i in faces:
        print i
```

I get somthing like this :((74, 22, 149, 149), 3)
What is all this information? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/objdetect_cascade_classification.html):

> The function finds rectangular regions in the given image that are
>   likely to contain objects the cascade has been trained for and returns
>   those regions as a sequence of rectangles....
>
> The function returns a list of tuples, (rect, neighbors) , where rect
>   is a CvRect specifying the object’s extents and neighbors is a number
>   of neighbors.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948055/classifiers-confidence-in-opencv-face-detector).